# JavaScript - Does this bookmarklet need some optimization?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm working on JavaScript [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that lets users send a text and link to a site.

This is the bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){new_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');new_script.src='http://bookmarklet.example.com/js/bookmarklet.js?v=1';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(new_script);new_script.type='text/javascript';})();
```

This is the JavaScript for it:

```
if(frames.length>0){
      F=' (Frames not supported)'
  } else {
      F=''
  }
  Q=document.getSelection();
  if(!Q){
 void(Q=prompt('Enter a text...'+F+'',''))      
  };
  if(Q){
      void (window.open('http://www.example.com/add?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location)+'&text='+escape(Q)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)))
  }
```

It's the first time I'm using JavaScript, so I would love to hear your feedback on the code. Is there anything that needs to be optimized?

Thanks.
Patrick

Comment: Where's the `void()` function defined and why are you using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loader could be simplified to the following:

```
javascript:(function () {document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'http://bookmarklet.example.com/js/bookmarklet.js?v=1'}());
```

- No more variables. By the way, you forgot to use `var`. It causes the variable to be declared as a global.
- Browsers, by default, parse script tags as JavaScript, thus the `type` can be omitted.

And in your script body, as far as I can understand, it's a script that gets a selected text or, if none selected, lets the user manually input the text and sends it to a server. Thus we have:

```
//remember that you are loading this script into the global scope. Protect your 
//variables by enclosing it in a closure
(function () {
      //a ternary if is a short 2-way evaluation (as far as reading is concerned)
  var F = (frames.length > 0) ? ' (Frames not supported)' : '',
      //the OR operator (`||`) could also be used to evaluate stuff
      //here, it returns either document.getSelection(), 
      //or if non existent, a prompted value
      Q = document.getSelection() || prompt('Enter a text...' + F + '', '');

  //then we execute your command
  window.open('http://www.example.com/add?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location) + '&text=' + escape(Q) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title))

}());
```

As an additional tip, I suggest you load the url to a hidden `iframe` for a cleaner interface. You could add listeners (there are hacks for cross domain iframe messaging), to detect a success and show a confirmation UI afterwards.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your feedback and suggestions! Quick question: I tried the bookmarklet in the Android browser (Android 4) but it's not working. The site loading bar starts but stops at ~20%. Is there a way to make it work for Android? `javascript:(function(){new_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');new_script.src='http://bookmarklet.example.com/js/bookmarklet.js?v=1';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(new_script);new_script.type='text/javascript';})();`

Comment: @Patrick Head over to StackOverflow if your code doesn't work on Android.